# Is list of Azure regions same for all subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azure-regions

There are several ways to get list of regions in Azure, for example `az account list-locations`...

Is this list same for all subscriptions and customers in Azure or can it happen that some subscription may see regions invisible for other? I mean still in scope of Azure Global cloud.

It is interesting that Listing regions by Azure SDK for .NET return empty property Subscription ID for region.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same for all subscriptions. From the documentation:

> "List supported regions for the current subscription"

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_account_list_locations